# Elastic boost score based on field value

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-7

I have documents in below format

```
{
     name:"Abc",
     newboostFactor: 1,
     boost: {
          boostType: "Type1",
          boostFactor: 1.000033
     }
}
```

I want to apply boostFactor based on boostType, suppose if boostType is "Type1" then boostFactor applied will be 1.000033

I am able to do this with just "newboostFactor" field with below query

```
{
  "explain": true, 
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "boost_mode": "sum",
      "functions": [
        {
          "field_value_factor": {
            "field": "newboostFactor",
            "factor": 1,
            "missing": 1
          }
        }
      ],
    },
  }
}
```

but how can i use boostFactor form boosts.boostFactor based on boosts.boostType

Comment: For dynamic values you can try with templates...create the script with place holder for boosting value